# Build a must-use plugin that tracks when other plugins are activated or deactivated

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks

Here I am trying to utilize add_action to add a callback function to the hooked action of 'deactivate_plugin', but my function is not echoing as I expect.

```
$plugin = 'polls_plugin';<br>
function detect_plugin_deactivation( $plugin ) {
    
    echo "$plugin was deactivated.";

}

add_action('deactivated_plugin', 'detect_plugin_deactivation', 10, 3);
```

Comment: `echo` probably won't work because it expects to output somewhere directly. Try a simple `fwrite()` or something that stores the information somewhere specific.

Comment: You could also try writing a message to the error_log if you're just trying to confirm your function is running. It's not really clear what it is that you are expecting to happen though?

Comment: All I was trying to do here was confirm that the function is running, so that I could know I was calling it correctly within add_action.  I am new to WP and PHP; I appreciate the help.